Why is my load function not setting the data correctly?
This is my first time attempting a save/load system.
I've read through the Godot docs carefully, and created a scene to test it out.
Both the save function is working perfectly, but the load function appears to be working correctly all the way up to the last line of code.
When I press the load button, it seems to load the saved data but doesn't set the "health" and "exp" values.
Here is the test scene I'm working with:

Here is the code for the object that I'm saving/loading:
extends Control



@export var health_in: int = 1
@export var current_health: int:
    set(health_update):
        current_health = health_update
        health_label.text = "HEALTH: " + str(current_health)
        print(current_health)

@export var exp_in: int = 1
@export var current_exp: int:
    set(exp_update):
        current_exp = exp_update
        exp_label.text = "EXP: " + str(current_exp)
        print(current_exp)

@onready var health_label = %HealthLabel
@onready var exp_label = %EXPLabel


func _ready():
    current_health = 0
    current_exp = 0


func _on_health_up_button_pressed():
    current_health += health_in


func _on_health_down_button_pressed():
    current_health -= health_in


func _on_exp_up_button_pressed():
    current_exp += exp_in


func _on_exp_down_button_pressed():
    current_exp -= exp_in


func _on_save_button_pressed():
    SaveGame.save_game()


func _on_load_button_pressed():
    SaveGame.load_game()


func save():
    var save_dict = {
        "filename" : get_scene_file_path(),
        "parent" : get_parent().get_path(),
        "health" : current_health,
        "exp" : current_exp
    }
    return save_dict

and here is my code for the save/load functions:
extends Node2D


func save_game():
    var save_file = FileAccess.open("user://savegame.save", FileAccess.WRITE)
    var save_nodes = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Persist")
    for node in save_nodes:
        if node.scene_file_path.is_empty():
            print("save file path is empty")
            continue
        if !node.has_method("save"):
            print("does not have save function")
            continue
        
        var node_date = node.call("save")
        var json_string = JSON.stringify(node_date)
        
        save_file.store_line(json_string)
        print("save successful")


func load_game():
    if not FileAccess.file_exists("user://savegame.save"):
        print("save state does not exist")
        return
    
    var save_nodes = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Persist")
    for i in save_nodes:
        i.queue_free()
    
    var save_file = FileAccess.open("user://savegame.save", FileAccess.READ)
    while save_file.get_position() < save_file.get_length():
        var json_string = save_file.get_line()
        var json = JSON.new()
        var parse_result = json.parse(json_string)
        
        if not parse_result == OK:
            print("error reading file")
            continue
        
        var node_data = json.get_data()
        var new_object = load(node_data["filename"]).instantiate()
        get_node(node_data["parent"]).add_child(new_object)
        
        for i in node_data.keys():
            if i == "filename" or i == "parent":
                continue
            new_object.set(i, node_data[i])
    print("load successful")

When I set the values for "health" and "exp" in the test scene, and press save, the file is saved correctly. I can even go to my custom directory and open the save file to see that it does in fact contain the correct data.


At first I thought it was because I was setting the values to 0 in the ready function, so I tried running it with that commented out. When I loaded the game, the label nodes were just set to their default text.
Then I thought maybe the load function was setting the values correctly, but it just wasn't being registered in the health and exp setter functions. So I had the ready function set each of the values to themselves (current_health = current_health). It didn't work.
At this point the only thing I can think of is that the last line in the load function is not setting the values at all.
